# Positioning a textbox beside an image using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on creating a simple textbox next to a positioned image using HTML and CSS. I am currently doing this by using a blue image sized to the same dimensions and then placing my text on top of it.

This is the current setup, its the image, followed by the blue box image with text placed on top:

[image: You can view the image here]

My HTML and CSS currently looks like this:

```html
<html>
<style>

p {
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  font-family: Arial;
}

h4 {
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bottom_container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.right-textbox {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40%;
}

.bottom__img {
  width: 40%;
}
</style>
    <div class="bottom_container">
        <img class="bottom__img" src="https://imgur.com/n8gXRcX.jpg" alt="PA State Capital Building" >
        <img class="bottom__img" src="https://imgur.com/xUIkixp.jpg" alt="" >
        <div class="right-textbox">
            <h4>The Pennsylvania State Capital</h4>
            <p>Text goes here</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

Could I use the background color for the textbox and somehow scale it to fit the same height and width of the main image instead of having to match it with a separate image of the same dimensions?

Comment: What your question/issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with CSS grid:

```css
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.bottom_container{
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 0.5em;
}
.right-textbox{
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom_container">
  <img class="bottom__img" src="https://imgur.com/n8gXRcX.jpg" alt="PA State Capital Building">
  <div class="right-textbox">
    <h4>The Pennsylvania State Capital</h4>
    <p>Text goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

or a flexible height approach:

```css
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.bottom_container{
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 0.5em;
}
.image-container{
  background-image: url("https://imgur.com/n8gXRcX.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
.right-textbox{
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom_container">
  <div class="image-container"></div>
  <div class="right-textbox">
    <h4>The Pennsylvania State Capital</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Learn more about CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Many thanks! This solved my issue, thank you for linking that CSS tricks page too!